# How do I call a c function from inside a mex file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a mexFunction defined in a .c file, written in the regular mex wrapper format. I would like to be able to call another function, written in C, from inside that first function. How can I do this? Do I need to create a regular .c file and just include it at the beginning of the first file? I would like to be able to pass variables from within the mex function to this secondary C function.

Comment: The `.c` files used by MEX are normal C source code, and function calls work normally.  Are you asking how to make the `mex` compiler link multiple `.c` files together?  `#include` should be an adequate workaround.

Comment: I see. As an alternative, would it make sense to define multiple functions inside one .c file, one of which is the gateway function which can call other functions in that file? Is that the standard way of doing it?

Comment: Sure.  It's C code, you can define functions and do everything else legal in C code.

Comment: You can also link object files this way.  See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22874460/2778484).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) has two subsections that describe how to build a MATLAB extension when the source code is spread over multiple source files.  Mostly, all you need to do is:

```
mex mexname.c helper1.c helper2.o
```

The result is automatically named according to the first file passed in.

For more information, read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) sections "Build MEX-File from Multiple Source Files" and "Create and Link to Separate Object Files".  There are also sections discussing using libraries.