# How to create mex file in matlab having just object file, without source?

Tags: matlab, static, compilation, mex

I have a precompiled static library propa64.a, which i want to use in Matlab in Linux. 
No source code of it available, only header file (propa.h). As far as i understand, to use it in Matlab i need to create mex file. How can i do it, without source and with only compiled propa64.a?

```
mex propa64.a
```

doesn't work, matlab says "mex: no filename given" error.
Any suggestions?
Or , may be it's possible to use pre-compiled static library in Matlab somehow else?

Comment: You _must_ write a MEX file, with a `mexFunction()`, including propa.h and linking with propa64.a. Build with the `mex` command [listing all the source, objects files and libraries as input arguments, but putting the MEX source file as the first argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22874460/2778484).

Comment: Ok, so as i don't have real source, i just copied the mexfunction.c (from '/extern/examples/mex/mexfunction.c') and named it propa.c. Then called mex: mex propa.c propa.h propa64.a 
But it stops on the propa.h, where there are calls to include windows.h, etc 
propa.h:1:21: error: windows.h: No such file or directory. mex: link of ' "propa.mexa64"' failed.
Looks like matlab can't find the called from propa.h other header files, which i know are in
'/usr/local/matlab-res.2012b/sys/lcc/include' folder, and this path is also in the 'path' variable. Any hints, what am i missing?